# How to publish data blended data sources?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a workbook with datasources blended and calculated fields referencing these datasources.

I get an error alert publishing to tableau server.

How do I publish the data sources?
I use tableau 2019[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you’d like people to help you, take some time to craft a concise question with enough detail and/or data, results to clearly describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an extract of the blended data source, and publish that extract to the server. This extract will included all the calculated fields that are included in the current workbook.

Comment: When I try publishing the secondary data source I get the notification in the image above

Comment: You should be able to create a new local data extract that combines the multiple data sources in your current workbook, along with calculated fields, parameters, and so on -- and then publish that extract to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for this type of use case I suggest publishing your data extracts separately. They can contain your calculated fields. Publishing the calculated fields is actually more performant anyway, many of them become materialised.

You can connect to both server data sources in desktop, and [perform the data blending within the Tableau workbook](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/data-blending-in-tableau/) using the published data sources. You can create additional calculated fields, including those from data blends, within the workbook. You're then able to publish the workbook and those calculated fields will remain at the workbook level, not the data source.

Other users connecting to the data sources will only see the calculations published into the extract, not the calculations published with the workbook.

Hope that makes sense.